# Where is Jbrk for J on Linux?

Tags: j

On windows and Mac I could click the yellow 'Jbrk' icon to break a time-consuming computation running in my Jqt session. How to do that on linux?

I don't want to kill the session, as there could be some useful variables living in the current locale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a J linux install the jbrk shell script will interrupt your Jqt session. That is, in the J install folder .../bin/jbrk will signal a break to the Jqt session.